# My shimano ultegra quick release is not working because the ball bearing inside got lost, can someone help me to identify the size of it?

Tags: road-bike, shimano, brakes, maintenance, bearings

Can someone help me because my ultegra caliper quick release system is not working because the ball bearing inside got lost (see picture below)

[image: Image captioned "Shimano Ultegra BR-6800 Quick Release Assembly - Front/Read - Y8LA98010" showing the 11 individual parts of the assembly. One, not highlighted, is a small ball bearing that is the subject of the question. No scale is provided.]

Comment: It is almost certainly between 3/16, 5/32, and 1/8, and probably 5/32 (they are sometimes encountered with Metric size names for the same bearings). If you just got one of each you'd likely come home with a match. Hardware stores of the sort that keep more extensive bulk fastener/hardware boxes usually have them by the each.

Comment: You could take apart the assembly from the other brake and measure it.

Comment: A bicycle shop should have bags of loose bearings. It shouldn't be too hard to work out the size. You could ask SJS!